# QT. Подключение dll библиотеки к проекту при использовании статического комплекта

Tags: qt, dll, fft

уважаемые форумчане. Возникла следующая задача - необходимо собрать проект на QT в один экзешник. 
С горем пополам собрал статический комплект, подключил и все работает, за исключением того момента, что, помимо стандартных кьютовских модулей типа charts и datavisualisation, используется библиотечка для БПФ fftw, которая раньше подключалась динамически и не входит в стандартную комплектацию QT. И вот с ней проблема- используя стат комплект, не могу динамически подключить её (по ТЗ её можно отдельно таскать).
В общем, вопрос в следующем - как заставить её работать? Покатит вариант и подключить как-то динамически и как-то пересобрать комплект, подсунув fftw в модули qt.
Собирал комплект по этому гайду https://vladsol.tk/2017/05/qt-5-8-0-static-build/.

Comment: В начале обрезалось "Добрый день, "

Comment: Александр, вопрос можно править, для этого под ним специальная кнопочка есть :)

Comment: у Александра её пока нет)

Comment: А по тз можно таскать библиотеки Qt отдельно тоже? Зачем статическая линковка? Я так понимаю, это продолжение Вашего предыдущего ответа. Может все таки динамическая линковка + windeployqt + Qt Installer Framework. Переформулируйте вопрос и я Вам выложу краткий туториал как собрать инсталлятор

Comment: Как собрать со всеми длл-ками я разобрался и windeplotqt освоил. Отдельно qt нельзя (свои заморочки), fftw можно. Сейчас интересует только лишь как подключить fftw к остальному

Comment: а, что за ошибка с FFTW? не должно быть разницы с тем, какая у вас Qt статическая или dll

Comment: Можно вообще использовать динамическую загрузку dll, тогда вообще не важно есть она или нет. Что-то типа:     `QLibrary lib("visa32");
    if (!lib.load()){
        return false;
    }
    using lviWrite = ViStatus (*)(ViSession, ViBuf, ViUInt32, ViPUInt32);
    auto write = reinterpret_cast<lviWrite> (lib.resolve("viWrite"));

    ViStatus status = write(visaSession,
                              reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(str.toLocal8Bit().data()),
                              static_cast<ViUInt32>(str.length()),
                              &retCount);`

Comment: @RomanOzhegov, да но тогда придется вручную вытаскивать из fftw указатели на функции и переделывать исходник по работе с бпф, если он уже написан

Comment: если вопрос просто получить приложение в одном exe, то можете собрать все в https://enigmaprotector.com/en/aboutvb.html
заодно можно часть ненужных библиотек от qt открутить (неиспользуемые imageformats и прочее)